Optimize or Eliminate UDF
I have multiple UDFs in a codebase I inherited. Is there any way to remove and implement without the UDF? I'm running on 1.3B rows, so every bit helps.
I considered using apply on a function, but could not get it to work.
# UDF to calculate seasonality, trend, and residual at the same time
@F.pandas_udf(ArrayType(StringType()))
def seasonality_trend_residual_udf(v: pd.Series) -> any:
    period_length = 52  # Set your desired period length here
    try:
        # Decompose the time series using the seasonal_decompose function
        decompose_output = seasonal_decompose(v, model='additive', period=period_length, extrapolate_trend='freq')

        # Get the last values for each component
        array_out = [
            str(decompose_output.seasonal.values[-1] if len(decompose_output.seasonal) > 0 else None),
            str(decompose_output.trend.values[-1] if len(decompose_output.trend) > 0 else None),
            str(decompose_output.resid.values[-1] if len(decompose_output.resid) > 0 else None)
            ]

    except Exception:
        # If there's an error in decomposition, return a dictionary with empty string values
        array_out = [str(None), str(None), str(None)]
    
    return array_out

# Function to apply seasonality, trend, and residual
def apply_seasonality_trend(df: DataFrame, date_col: str, value_col: str, partition_cols: list, period_length: int) -> DataFrame:
    window_spec = Window.partitionBy(partition_cols).orderBy(date_col).rowsBetween(-2 * period_length, 0)  # Adjust based on your period length
    
    df = df.withColumn(f'udf_output', seasonality_trend_residual_udf(F.col(value_col)).over(window_spec))
    df = (df
          .withColumn('category_fcst_volume_sales_seasonality', F.col('udf_output').getItem(0))
          .withColumn('category_fcst_volume_sales_trend', F.col('udf_output').getItem(1))
          .withColumn('category_fcst_volume_sales_residual', F.col('udf_output').getItem(2))
          .drop('udf_output'))
    
    return df


Could you add more context on the objective that you want to achieve? Also, could you add some example data and expected output?

Also, could you explain the logic of your function? For example what is seasonal_decompose

The three components of seasonal_decompose's result are arrays containing time series. The last values of the time series are of course somehow related to the input but if you only look at the last values you get more or less random values. To improve the performance you could basically skip most of the calculation. It depends on what you want to achieve...
